# Taxonomia personalizada no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, taxonomia

Tenho um cadastro de posts, que na verdade é um cadastro de médicos.
Minha dúvida é como fazer o direcionamento para um arquivo `taxonomy.php` específico, pois tenho dois arquivos com seus respectivos `select`s no banco. Em um mostro uma informação e no outro, outras. Sendo mais específico, o que difere um do outro são informações a mais(datas, etc) que um tem e o outro não tem, mas são basicamente as mesmas infomações. Só não sei como direcionar para o outro arquivo, já que o padrão é o `taxonomy.php`.

Comment: Creio que possa te ajudar. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43624/how-to-choose-which-template-to-be-used-for-multiple-taxonomy-query

Answer (score 0):

São taxonomias diferentes?

Caso positivo você pode utilizar: `taxonomy-nome-da-taxonomia.php`

E utilizar o seu código em cada uma.

Comment: Sim, são diferentes, inclusive tenho os dois arquivos das duas taxomias. O problema é que não sei como e onde fazer essa vinculação no Wordpress.